# Debug application from the Device in iPhone?

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

I was debugging an iPhone application from the device. At that time the following message was printed on the console:

```
[Session started at 2011-03-30 11:15:42 +0530.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-182-66
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 173.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 173.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug an ad hoc or app store build?  I've seen this error in those cases.  Switch to a Debug configuration and I think it'll work.

Comment: I said "Switch to a Debug configuration and I think it'll work".   More importantly, make sure you are not using a distribution certificate to sign the configuration which you are trying to debug.    I've seen it do this when trying to debug an Ad Hoc build on the device.  I suspect a security block, but am not sure.